Looker data studio: sum over running total formula
I have the following table.

The raw data columns are:

Fruit
Sweetness
Number of fruits

weighted_ is equal to Fruit * Sweetness
i want the tes weigthed values is 8,750,000 from the first row unit the end which similar as sum(weigthed_) over()
How do i do this in Looker Data Studio?
Does Looke Data Studio support windows function?

Just to check, do you want tes weigthed to = 8,750,000 on all rows of your table?

yes @Max_Stone how do i do that?

Unfortunately there is not a windows function equivalent in Looker studio but you can get the result that you are looking for using a blend to join two tables together.

Create a calculated field in your data by clicking on the "add a field " button the "add calculated field" and in the formula just enter the number 1 add the field name (anything you want) and click save.
Add the new field to your table, every entry should be 1.
Copy and paste the table in your worksheet select both tables, right click and select blend data.
In the blend you should see between the two tables a venn diagram, click on the pencil to edit and in the join conditions link the tables based only the new field that you have created and click Save.
Add all the fields from table 1 and just the field you created and weighted from table 2, on the right hand side rename the field Weighted(table two) to tes weigthed and click Save.
Create a new table with the blended data source and tes weigthed should be 8,750,000 for all products

